# Cannot add <div> to Youtube in a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I can't add a `<div>` to Youtube but don't know why.

My Javascript code:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.id="divsn";
div.style.display='none';
div.style.width = "500px";
div.style.height = "400px";
div.style.background = "#C2E2FF";
div.style.display='block';

document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
document.getElementById("divsn").style.fontStyle = 'italic';
document.getElementById("divsn").style.marginTop = "560px";
document.getElementById("divsn").style.marginLeft = "460px";
document.getElementById("divsn").style.position = "absolute";
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not on the page? It has `display:none` so it wouldn't be visible.

Comment: no no i have set the other properties which i did not showed.. sory . like div.style.display='block'; document.getElementById("divsn").style.fontStyle = 'italic';
document.getElementById("divsn").style.marginTop = "560px";
document.getElementById("divsn").style.marginLeft = "460px";
document.getElementById("divsn").style.position = "absolute";

Comment: i dont know why div is not being displayed . :(

Comment: You need to show a complete example, then. The code in the question works.

Comment: this is my complete code which i showed

Comment: this code works fine in chrome but not working in firefox..

Comment: "i have set the other properties which i did not showed" and "this is my complete code which i showed" are contradictory. Did you show the complete code or not?

Comment: ok well you are not understanding i have showed you the other set properties in comment .. one minute i will edit my code in question

Comment: now tell me please what is mistake??

Comment: It's still `display:none`.

Comment: sorry for these stupid mistakes actually i have used block in real code but in hurry doing these mistakes.

Comment: Where have you placed this code?

Comment: Again: **Where is this code?**. From your other question, I'm inclined to assume in a XUL overlay script, but I hate guessing.

Comment: my internet was down . you are right in overlay script . in overlay.js file my code is placed